# How do I get autocompletion to work for Bootstrap 5 in JetBrains IDE

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, jetbrains-ide

My IDE autocompletion is not working when I call Bootstrap 5 from CDN.

Answer (score 2):

The IDE relies on calling for Bootstrap 5 in your node requirements.

Inside your terminal

For NPM

```
npm init -y

npm -i bootstrap@next --save-dev
```